# Css flip animation - "fold" one div under another

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to get effect when one div is being "folded" under another one.
I' cant make it rotate on the left side.

Sorry for the drawing:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
  .flipper:hover  {    
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j939t/93/)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is change the transform origin of your element. Currently it would seem that the rotation is happening from the center of the element, meaning that your origin is `50% 50%` on the `x` and `y` axis.

You can use `transform-origin: 0 0;` (or `-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;` in your case) to override the original origin definition.

Notice: In my **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j939t/96/)** I added a parent element in order to attach the `:hover` to it. If the hover would have been on the `.flipper` element than once the element would move you will no long hover it.

Comment: * webkit still needs the prefix '-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden' to see the element going under and not on top in chrome.. also transition should be set on the original element (!:hover) like so: http://jsfiddle.net/j939t/97/